# c# How to convert Object to XML

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization, xml-serialization, silverlight-5.0

I am c# and silverlight 5 beginner. I have to clear one omportanyt doubt with senior developers in silverlight.

I have an object in c# and i have to obtain xml corresponding to that object.

**Could some one explain through an example how to do that(any simple example of class and it's object and then xml obtained)**

I have read on google some document and they discuss some method call `serialize()` capable of doing so. Am i right ?  But how it do so could some one please explain throught c# class and it's object and xml obtained ?

Would be a big help. 
EDIT:
My try is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public static class Xml
    {
        public static string ToXml(this object objectToSerialize)
        {
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
            ser.Serialize(mem, objectToSerialize);
            var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            return utf8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

The next class is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public  class Parameter 
    { 
        public  string Name {get; set; } 
    }  
}
```

The Main function containing class is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public static class ControlClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Parameter pram = new Parameter();
            pram.ToXml();

        }

    }
}
```

And the error obtained is:

```
Error   1   'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

CORRESPONDING TO THE LINE/

```
return utf8.GetString(mem.ToArray()); in Xml class. How toma the solution of it ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourData));
serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
string xml = writer.ToString();
```

[See also MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I have already seen the link but they dont't show the xml obtained on class. Could you please give me a sample of the class and then xml obtained on this applying the logic you gave to that class object ? Thanks

Comment: @user234839 you see the last line, where I do `string xml = writer.ToString();`, well... that's the bit where we obtain the `string` that the serializer wrote as xml. Basically, serializers typically write to either a `Stream` or some kind of `*Writer` (in this case a `TextWriter`). I'm using `StringWriter` to buffer the data into a `StringBuilder`, then obtain the xml via `.ToString()`

Comment: @user234839 if you mean examples of a class and the resultant xml: again, see MSDN - it has examples there. Look inside the link I posted for `public class MyClass`

Comment: Thanks both of you. Let me implement it wil come back to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use this class

```
public static class Xml
{
    public static string ToXml(this object objectToSerialize)
    {
        var mem = new MemoryStream();
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(mem, objectToSerialize);
        var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        return utf8.GetString(mem.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
    }
}
```

With this extension method you can do

```
var xml = your_object.ToXml();
```

Comment: @Marco I have already seen the link but they dont't show the xml obtained on class. Could you please give me a sample of the class and then xml obtained on this applying the logic you gave to that class object ? Thanks

Comment: @user234839: There's already an example you can use `var xml = your_object.Serialize();` :)

Comment: Thanks both of you. Let me implement it wil come back to mark it as answer.

Comment: Error 1 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class  and pointing to "utf8 " in line var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

Comment: Error 1 'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is inaccessible due to its protection level  corresponding to line return utf8.GetString(mem.ToArray());

Comment: @user234839: your class must be defined as public!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54018/discussion-between-user234839-and-marco).