# How to specify the expected response content-type in a http request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http

My client needs to get his data in a .Net Dataset data type represented in XML format. Currently my API returns a `List<Gifts>` in JSON type. How can I make such this request?

In client (which is Asp.NET Web API):

```
var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MyExpected-Content-Type", "Dataset");
var response = await myHttpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);
```

In server (which is Asp.NET Core Web API):

```
if (Request.Headers["MyExpected-Content-Type"] == "Dataset")
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // ...
    return Ok(ds.GetXml());
}
else
{
    var lst = new List<Gifts>();
    // ...
    return Ok(lst);
}
```

Comment: Pls feel free to let me know if it worked for you. And if you think my post below is helpful to you, could you pls click the √ beside it to accept it as the answer and it may make it easier for others who have similar issue to find it.

Comment: In fact, I'm looking for a standard header name + value to replace with "MyExpected-Content-Type", something like this:
"Accept" = "application/xml:dataset"

Answer (score 1):

Modify the Program.cs to add XML format ability.

`builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();`

Then in the Controller method, add `[Produces("application/xml")]` above the method, code like below will return XML result.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync() {
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    user.userName = "user1";
    user.Password = "pwd";
    return Ok(user);
}
```

[image]

=========================================

Does this what you want? I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191327) to return XML, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23733391) for converting a model to xml string.

```
public IActionResult getHeader() {
            if (Request.Headers["MyExpected-Content-Type"] == "Dataset") {
                var user = new UserModel { age= 1, name="user1" };
                var writer = new StringWriter();
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserModel));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, user);
                string xml = writer.ToString();
                return new ContentResult
                {
                    ContentType = "application/xml",
                    Content = xml,
                    StatusCode = 200
                };
            }
            else
            {
                var xml = "<result><value>hello</value></result>";
                return new ContentResult
                {
                    ContentType = "application/xml",
                    Content = xml,
                    StatusCode = 200
                };
            }
            
        }
```

Here's my testing result:

[image]